# Gracefully stopping embedded jetty server on issuing of kill command in linux

Tags: java, linux, jetty

In my embedded Jetty server application, I want to close some streams, executors, etc before it is killed by kill -9 command in linux. How do I handle that ?

I observed that when my jetty server is running and I issue a kill -9 command, then "Killed" strings print in logs and application closes.

I already have added LifeCycleListener added as connector to server so that if my server stops, I can do some cleanup before application goes down. But this doesn't get called in case of kill -9

```
    server = new Server();
    loadConnectors(server);

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");

    server.setHandler(context);

    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/*");
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

    // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", Resources.class.getCanonicalName());

    server.setStopAtShutdown(true); 
    server.start();
    logger.debug("Reached this line");



  private void loadConnectors(Server server) {
    //----Http connection setup------------------
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(9025);
    connector.addLifeCycleListener(new ConnectorListener());
            .....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `kill -9` will always result in a harsh termination of the JVM.

There's nothing that Jetty can do to work around that.

Consider instead using a command on your webserver (password protected obviously) that will just issue a `Server.stop()`.

Or use JMX and and call the Server's `stop()` method. (this can be done via a JMX console / JMX browser / or even a JMX command line)

Answer (score 0):

You can only listen on `KILLSIG 15` (kill -15) with a Runtime.addShutdownHook() like `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread());`

Comment: Jetty registers Runtime shutdown hooks already, no need to add one manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, sorry. `SIGKILL` (9) and `SIGSTOP` (19 on linux, 23 on Solaris) cannot be ignored or caught.